# Naming convention for MongoDB in combination with Play Framework (Scala)

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

With regards to mongoDB, then everything is clear and on this subject much has been written. Use javascript syntax (first_name and even better "fn" to save space).
But what about the work in the scala code (I use camelCase). For example, I would have written such a hierarchy

```
case class User (... personalInfo: PersonalInfo, ...)
case class PersonalInfo (... fullName: FullName, ...)
case class FullName (firstName: String, middleName: Option [String], lastName: String)
```

If I want to work with mongoDB simply (namely use JSON Macro Inception and do not write custom readers and writers), I must change these classes something like this

```
case class User (... p_inf: PersonalInfo, ...)
case class PersonalInfo (... f_nm: FullName, ...)
case class FullName (fn: String, mn: Option [String], ln: String)
```

But this code looks ugly for me (as the reduction of words, and a whole style)

```
val firstName = user.p_inf.f_nm.fn
```

I'm going to make another constant for the fields, which are then used in javascript/html code (and here this style is suitable), for example

```
trait JsFields {
val jsFirstName = "p_inf.f_nm.fn"
}
```

user.scala.html:

```
import ... JsFields._
<input name="@jsFirstName" />
```

So MongoDB and JS/html styles are appropriate, but the business logic is not. 
Please write best naming practice in conjunction MongoDB/Play Framework with Scala/Html/JS. Please with examples (e.g. fields above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo 3 adds compression with the Wired Tiger engine, so you probably don't need or want to use obscure names anymore.

https://comerford.cc/2014/11/12/mongodb-2-8-new-wiredtiger-storage-engine-adds-compression/

The actual JIRA ticket where it was implemented:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-164

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Crosmer. it is good news. but how to be with underline. is it normal practice to write personal_info.first_name in Scala in this case?

Comment: I don't know what the normal practice is for mongo + scala + multiword variables, but in our project we use scala naming conventions, e.g. "personalInfo.firstName".  Most of the time we are working with Scala code, not Javascript.